# How jquery script file gets the ID value of Asp.Net MVC 3's route data?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3

The URL is `http://localhost:52974/App/Detail/23432`. I know the following code can get the ID (*23432*) and it can be used in javascript code embedded in a cshtml file.

```
@ViewContext.RouteData.Values["id"]
```

However, I have an external jQuery script file which handle document.ready function. The following approach will not work because it's not a cshtml file. What's the best approach to get the MVC route ID value besides using javascript to parse the URL?

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var id = @ViewContext.RouteData.Values["id"];
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I would get the view to render out a script tag that would invoke a call to an init function in the external js passing the id as a param.

view:

```
<script>
   app.init('@ViewContext.RouteData.Values["id"]');
</script>
```

external js:

```
var app = {};

(function(app){

    var _id;

    app.init = function(id){
         _id = id;
    }

})(app);
```

Answer (score 7):

You could store the value in a hidden input field in you view;

```
<input type="hidden" value='@ViewContext.RouteData.Values["id"]' id="routeDataId />
```

and then in your jQuery script;

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var id = $('#routeDataId').val();

    // The rest of your script
});
```

Then you'll have access to the ID from your external script too :)

Answer (score 0):

```
var id = @HttpContext.Current.Request.RequestContext.RouteData.Values["ID"].ToString();
```